# I wonder how clustering algorithms are used in which all real world applications?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, partitioning

What all are applications of clustering algorithms? Which all real world applications use clustering algorithms and for what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just some example applications:

- **Biology**: classification of plants and animals given their features;
- **City-planning**: identifying groups of houses according to their house type, value and geographical location;
- **Earthquake studies**: clustering observed earthquake epicenters to identify dangerous zones;
- **Insurance**: identifying groups of motor insurance policy holders with a high average claim cost; identifying frauds;
- **Libraries**: book ordering;
- **Marketing**: finding groups of customers with similar behavior given a large database of customer data containing their properties and past buying records;
- **WWW**: document classification; clustering weblog data to discover groups of similar access patterns.

[Source](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/)

Another **excessive list** of [applications of cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Applications) from **Wikipedia**

Comment: Should be -1 for mentioning 'Marketing' on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MartinJames: Evens out with the +1 for 'Earthquake studies', no? ;)